# Find Options text in Dropdown and set selected and change text

Tags: javascript

with vanilla javascript I'd like to loop through my dropdown, and change the selected one, and then change the text that is displayed.   I have it selecting, but I'm not getting the object name correct to change the optionText? of the item.

```
var textToFind = 'LdapUsers';

var dd = document.getElementById('membershipProvider');
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
        i.options.text = "Edgewood Login";  //This is WRONG
        break;
    }
}
```

guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `querySelector` and a selector to access it without a loop.

```js
v = "222";

selProvider = document.querySelector("#membershipProvider option[value='" + v + "']");

if (selProvider) {
  selProvider.text = "CHANGED!";
  selProvider.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select id="membershipProvider">
  <option value='111'>AAA</option>
  <option value='222'>BBB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh I like not looping, I need to also set it to be the selected option

Comment: It wasn't changing what I was seeing, I realize I had to change label as well so I added selProvider.label = "Changed"     Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the option at that index. Right now you are trying to modify the index itself.

should be:

```
dd.options[i].text
```

not

```
i.options.text
```

```js
var textToFind = 'LdapUsers';

var dd = document.getElementById('membershipProvider');
for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
    if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
        dd.options[i].text = "Edgewood Login";  //This is WRONG
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="membershipProvider">
  <option value="cifs">CIFS</option>
  <option value="LdapUsers">LdapUsers</option>
  <option value="nfs">NFS</option>
  <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ya I had tried that and I didn't see the display change.   I just noticed that worked but what I see in the code is correct, but what's being displayed is still LdapUsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
dd.options[i].text = "Edgewood Login";
```

just like when checking for its value